# Is there any conflicts between running rkhunter and chkrootkit on one system?

Tags: malware, rootkit, rkhunter, chkrootkit

Can I run rkhunter and chkrootkit at the same time on my Ubuntu Linux laptop without having to worry about conflicts?

Comment: I wouldn't try running both at the same time; But I do have both installed and run one at a time without issues. Suggestion: Include the reason for running both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is first scheduling to run chkrootkit and then schedule to run rkhunter 5 minutes after, so that they dont run at the same time, otherwise rkhunter will report false positives when checking open ports (if you have set rkhunter to run skdet and unhide it takes longer to scan)